# Foundation 4 Custom Dropdown menu not binding data

Tags: html, forms, zurb-foundation

I've implemented a Foundation 4 Dropdown within a form I am using.

The custom drop down menu is not binding to the corresponding value of the item I am clicking on.

In a list of 4  tags the first item will be selected correctly but all others will bind to the item before it...

```
Binds to option 1 - <li class="">Mr</li>
Binds to option 1 - <li class="">Mrs</li>
Binds to option 2 - <li class="">Miss</li>
Binds to option 3 <li class="">Ms</li>

1 - <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
2 - <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
3 - <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
4 - <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
```

Strangely when you click or select for the second time it binds to the correct item.

I've replicated several tests with similar results.

Has anyone come across anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're truly using a Zurb Foundation drop down element, then it would be wise to use Zurb's syntax for creating a drop down menu. Generally, this is the syntax that should be used for a DropDown Button:

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop" class="button dropdown">Dropdown Button</a><br>
<ul id="drop" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>
```

OR for a basic DropDown control:

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1">Has Dropdown</a>
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
  <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop2">Has Content Dropdown</a>
<div id="drop2" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown content">
  <p>Some text that people will think is awesome! Some text that people will think is awesome! Some text that people will think is awesome!</p>
</div>
```

More documentation can be found on Zurb's Foundation website: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown_buttons.html
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html

If I have not answered your question or perhaps misunderstood your question, or you believe this is a bug in one of the Foundation libraries, I also recommend upgrading to Foundation5 (which is the latest version, released fairly recently).

I hope this helps a little bit. Let me know if I've misunderstood or can help further.

-Mike